# Where should the implementation of com.ibm.websphere.crypto.KeyGenerator in WebSphere be placed?

Tags: security, websphere, key-generator, keyset

For KeySet configuration in WebSphere, I have to provide implementation of com.ibm.websphere.crypto.KeyGenerator interface. I dont know where to place this implementation class on Server.

Comment: Is this WAS traditional?

Comment: @Alasdair WAS Network Deployment 9.0.0.9

Comment: In that case I think you put it in lib/ext of the install

Comment: @Alasdair I have deploed it in /lib and it worked! Thanks